# How to change netmask with iproute2?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, iproute2

With ifconfig we can change the netmask with the folowing:

```
ifconfig eth0 netmask <new netmask>
```

How can we do this with the command ip?

I know ifconfig is deprecated and this mostly why I would like to do it the iproute2 way.

My objective is to extend our current network from a /24 to a /21 on-the-fly without disturbing services running on our servers. As a workaround currently I simply add a new route to the /21 and eventually a planned network restart will officialize the change. It works but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
ip address add 1.2.3.4/21 dev <device>
ip address del 1.2.3.4/24 dev <device>
```

(Where 1.2.3.4 is your current IP). `ip address show` Will list all of the assigned addresses.

Comment: Wow this works. I though I tried it with a resulting error problably a mistake. And this is better then ifconfig conterpart, with the ifconfig solution routes were dropped.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still amazed by how powerful `ip` is. Also you get to shorten most of the keywords to two or three characters, which makes you look like a ninja when someone is watching you type. :)

Comment: Is this really the supposed way to do it? When I try this with ipv6 addresses I get "RTNETLINK answers: File exists"